# Access data entry with subforms

Tags: ms-access, subforms

I have a **form** with 13 **subforms** (each in separate tab page). Those subforms are link to the form with primary key `ID`. The `ID` is generated on the fly by 3 fields on the form.

The problem is when I have filled those 3 fields (and have `ID` generated) and jumps to the tab control, the tab page with first subform freeze.

I **expected** the cursor to go to the first field of the subform.

Current **workaround** is pressing `Esc` once so that I can focus the control in the subform.

What could be the **cause** of this problem and how could I **solve** this?

*Edited*: I set the **lock** in the subforms record. I removed those and it is working ok and finished entering data of 400 variables x 450 sets of question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if Access is getting confused, as you're only generating the new record & associated key once the first page of the subform is completed.

From my experience of Access, it's usually better to let the auto primary key functions do the work, rather than generate a composite key.

As such, could you generate a primary key independently (ie have an auto number), and use this as the association between the subsequent subforms?